# How can I get control+left arrow to go back one word in iTerm2?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, iterm, iterm2

I was reading up in the Linux manual and I noticed that it said I could use control+left and control+right to move forward and back words in the terminal while editing.

> "Pressing Ctrl plus the Left or Right arrow key moves backward or forward a word at a time, as does pressing Esc and then B or F."

On OS X `control+left` and `control+right` normally control spaces. I have disabled those. I also tried to use the preferences pane to set the keyboard shortcuts:

[image]

[image]

However this does not work and causes this error:

[image]

Also, if I am in iTerm and use `alt+escape` then B or F the character moves back and forth. This was happening before any of my config changes. But I'd really like to be able to use control + the arrow keys.

Comment: Incidentally, a more parsimonious way to achieve this might simply be to map command+left and command+right instead of ctrl+left and ctrl+right. I didn't need to disable anything system-wide to accomplish this.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

### bash

Just add the following to `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
```

See [this archived Wiki post](https://iterm2.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/Keybindings.wiki) for some more explanation. If you want to use the <kbd>alt</kbd> key instead for word-to-word movement (like default OS X behavior), use:

```
"\e[1;9D": backward-word
"\e[1;9C": forward-word
```

### zsh

zsh by default does not use the `readline` library and therefore won't read `~/.inputrc`. To get the same functionality, you could add the following to your `~/.zshrc` to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>:

```
bindkey -e
bindkey '\e\e[C' forward-word
bindkey '\e\e[D' backward-word
```

To use the <kbd>alt</kbd> key:

```
bindkey -e
bindkey '^[[1;9C' forward-word
bindkey '^[[1;9D' backward-word
```

See [this documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Zle-Builtins) for more about the built-in zsh line editor (zle).

---

Why is this? You've set up your profile to use the Xterm defaults:

[image]

This is why you'll need to "catch" this sequence and tell `readline` what to do.

---

If the above still doesn't work and you are using OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) or there abouts, you probably need to disable the global Mission Control shortcuts which prevent Control+arrow keys from reaching iTerm, even if Mission Control itself is disabled. You can do so from *System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Mission Control*:

[image: mission control keyboard prefs]

Comment: I try to follow the instruction to get the alt + left and alt + right keys working. I added the two lines to my .inputrc file, but the only thing what happens when I press the keys is that either a "D" or a "C" gets printed to the shell. I'm using iTerm2 with zsh shell. Any ideas?

Comment: @Flo Try adding the lines `bindkey -e`, `bindkey '^[[1;9C' forward-word` and `bindkey '^[[1;9D' backward-word` to your `~/.zshrc` instead. IIRC zsh won't read `.inputrc` – or at least it works for me this way.

Comment: @slhck, sure I will create a new question, though alt+left does work on vim, alt+right doesn't. Very weird, I will create a new question now.

Comment: @Ben No idea, sorry! I'm really just the guy who uses vim for commit messages  and quick fixes. I bountied your question so you'd get more attention on it.

Comment: ***UGH, god***, THANK YOU.  especially for the `zsh` specific info.  I was going to ***SCREAM*** if I typed `D` oe more time!

Comment: Not working for me with ctrl-left/right + bash, but works fine if I set it up for alt-left/right.

Comment: Added an edit about Mission Control shortcuts preventing any of this from working in the most aggravatingly opaque manner. Hopefully it saves someone from going through the same thing I just did urgh...

Comment: For OSX + zsh + iTerm2 + ctrl-left/right use the following:
`bindkey -e; bindkey '\e\e[C' forward-word; bindkey '\e\e[D' backward-word`

Comment: For some reason my OSX preferences were restored to defaults..

Comment: This works but only in the local shell.  If I ssh to another box it only moves 1 character.  In the default terminal app ^left and ^right work locally and remotely.  Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Disregard.  I just needed to start a new ssh session!

Comment: @ArturBodera thanks for posting! works perfectly and interprets holding the arrow key down as repeated movements, rather than having to press the arrow key each time for each word (which I had to do with the BetterTouchTool solution http://superuser.com/a/584175/83693)

Comment: The link http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/Keybindings is dead, do you know where is it relocated to?

Comment: @gerrytan You can still access it through the [Wayback Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20121226151631/http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/Keybindings).

Comment: You really don't need `bindkey -e` to make this work. Maybe you just like EMACS and are trying subconsciously bring people to it. Try it with `bindkey -v` for `vi`.

Comment: What worked for me in ~/.zprofile to navigate words with Control+Arrows is the following:

`bindkey -e` 
`bindkey '^[[1;5C' forward-word`
`bindkey '^[[1;5D' backward-word`

Answer (score 110):

Working solution for zsh. Simple, straightforward, out-of-the-box.

1. Goto:
   `⌘, Preferences → Profiles → Keys → Keyboard Behavior`
2. Load Preset: `Natural Text Editing`

[image: Load Preset "Natural Text Editing"]

Comment: Thanks @Happy Torturer, I believe it's best answer mostly because I don't have on plain Terminal.app that problem so I don't want to modify bash/zsh, just want to work everything like in Terminal.app.

Comment: This, this, this. Thank you so much for this solution! I've gone through this maddening process with each Mac I get. I now know the simplest way to make this happen. Thank you!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I wonder, is there any way to load this preset from the command line rather than going through the settings GUI?

Comment: This should've improved the @rassom answer rather than providing a same answer with screenshot.

Comment: Worked for me, but I needed to also disable misson control shortcuts that were having higher priority, once disabled that "Naturel Text Editing" worked

Comment: I appear to be missing this preset :/

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 21):

I fixed it this way:

In top menu; go to

```
Profiles 
-> Open profiles... 
-> Edit profiles... (button) 
-> Keys (tab) 
-> Load Preset... (dropdown) 
->  Choose "Natural text editing". Done! :-)
```

[image]

Comment: all i have under that preset is "Factory Defaults"

Comment: Same, only "Factory defaults"

Answer (score 7):

I used a different approach. Using [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/) I programmed a custom keyboard shortcut for iTerm2. When I press alt-left in iTerm2, it sends the keyboard shortcut ctrl-left with the action "Send keyboard shortcut to specific application". The application is iTerm2. I did the same for alt-right mapped to ctrl-right.

The effect is that pressing alt-left or alt-right in iTerm sends a ctrl-left or ctrl-right directly to iTerm2, bypassing the usual system-wide shortcut to move a desktop left or right. Like this I get the typical mac behaviour in iTerm2, on local terminal sessions, but also on remote SSH sessions and I can use the standard ctrl-left / ctrl-right to move to different desktops. I wrote it up here:

http://www.callum-macdonald.com/2013/04/17/ctrl-left-and-ctrl-right-on-iterm2/

Comment: BetterTouchTool is not open source and could very well be doing things you wish it wasn't. The guy says he's a student but he could just as well be a three letter agency.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, I found the easiest solution was to go to my profile settings (found in Profiles/Keys), removing the offending profile shortcuts(as profile overrides global in iTerm), in my case alt+left and alt+right and then the global shortcuts worked perfectly for me!

Also, if you're using OS X, it's probably best to stick with system wide shortcuts, i.e. using alt+left and alt+right instead for this purpose, having different behaviour in terminal is bound to cause a pain eventually.

Other than that chmac's solution to use Better Touch Tool was an elegant way to change control+arrow's behaviour in iterm only.

Comment: actually this is the best solution. It is confusing as most of us go to `Keys` tab. Instead we have to go to `Profiles` tab -> A profile(eg default) -> keys.

Comment: This is definitely the safest and easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

This post teaches this and others shortcuts as ⌥←Delete to delete a word:

http://elweb.co/making-iterm-2-work-with-normal-mac-osx-keyboard-shortcuts/

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, which is about using <ctrl><left>

Comment: All you have to do is use the shortcut that fits your need. "<ctrl><left>" or whatever you want.

Comment: So please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into the `Profiles` tab and delete the mapping for <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> as by default it outputs some hex values.

Comment: This did it for me!

Answer (score 0):

**In the newer versions of iTerm (as of writing `3.4.19`):**

Navigate to
<kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Profiles</kbd> → <kbd>Keys</kbd> → <kbd>Key Mappings</kbd>.

From <kbd>Presets</kbd> dropdown, select <kbd>Natural Text Editing</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Saved me tons of headache.

Comment: what does this answer bring in addition to the two others that mention Natural Text Editing, while those ones also have screenshots ?