# How to move back a word in OS X Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal.app

If I ssh into a Linux box I can move back a word in the CLI using <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Is there a way I can do this in the Mac's Terminal?  Every time I press <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>, `[D` returns.

Comment: For iTerm, see: [How can I get control+left arrow to go back one word in iTerm2?](http://superuser.com/questions/357355/how-can-i-get-controlleft-arrow-to-go-back-one-word-in-iterm2?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>esc</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> is the key binding to go back a word.

<kbd>esc</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> moves forward.

Answer (score 3):

In your Terminal's preferences, set the following keyboard mapping if it's not already set:

[image]

Your *Option cursor left* should map to `\033b`, and *Option cursor right* to `\033f`. Now, pressing <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> will move back or forward a word, like they do in normal text editing windows.

If you additionally tick *Use option as meta key*, pressing <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> will have the same effect, since these are the standard shell bindings for word movement.

Of course, if you really want <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>⌫</kbd> to move back a word (and not delete it), then map this combination to `\033b` instead.